# Утечка памяти при использовании NewByteArray

Tags: java, c

Будет ли утечка памяти в java в таком случае? Вот код на java:

```
import java.io.*;

class Main {
    private native byte[] get_byte();

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {    
        Console cons = System.console();
        String pwd;
        while ( true ) {
            pwd = cons.readLine ( );
            byte[] test = new Main().get_byte ( );

            test[0] = '1';
            pwd = cons.readLine ( );
            System.out.println ( "Новый цикл." );    
        }
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary ( "Main" );
    }
}
```

А вот jni код.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Main.h"

JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_Main_get_1byte ( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj ) {
    jbyteArray test = (*env)->NewByteArray ( env, 255 );             
    return test;
}
```

Мне в другом месте посоветовали использовать DeleteLocalRef, но я так понял что он освобождает память, типа `free()`. А мне надо выделить память и чтобы в java сборщик мусора очистил её. правильно ли я делаю? Да, и ещё, у меня линукс и стоит openjdk. может вы заодно подскажете как утечку памяти проверить?

Comment: я верно понял, вы выделяете память вне сборщика мусора, а вручную, но ждете, что сборщик её освободит?

Comment: @tym32167 да. я щас открыл книгу по jni, и там написано что слабая глобальная ссылка может быть только освобождена сборщиком мусора. но я пока не пойму как это.

Comment: @tym32167 а что если выделять память вне сборщика мусора, а когда надо освободить память, тоже обращаться к jni, и там в функции удалять данные?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Хотел бы подсказать, но у меня нет опыта с jni.

Answer (score 0):

Утечка будет - буфер необходимо освобождать. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574241/jni-newbytearray-memory-leak) описывается решение похожего вопроса.
После использования буфера необходимо его удалить.

```
env->DeleteLocalRef(jBuff)
```

Можно например делать это переопределив метод `finalize()` (для Java до 9ой версии) либо где-то в своем коде тогда когда буфер уже не нужен.

Comment: ну так как же его освобождать, если он нужен в java коде? Я решил его потом освобождать, сделать типа функции free в jni, в которую из java можно передать буфер и освободить с помощью DeleteLocalRef.

Comment: Вы привели пример и задали вопрос про будет утечка - в вашем примере она будет. Если вы сделаете так, как  я написал в ответе и будете руками ее высвобождать когда она вам будет не нужна, тогда все будет ок.